# Redirect all urls with subdirectories to root except two

Tags: php, .htaccess, exception, redirect

I changed the link structure of one of my sites recently and need to 301 redirect:

all links with subdirs to their version without subdirs (i.e. just making the subdir disappear)

e.g.

```
domain.com/fdfddffd/test -> domain.com/test
domain.com/yipeee/test -> domain.com/test
domain.com/fdfddffd/aaa -> domain.com/aaa etc.
```

So I thought about using

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)(.*)$     / [R]
```

but I need to exclude two directories from that, one is "search", the other is "data". How do I combine the above rewrite rule with the exclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `RewriteCond` to exclude those two with an expression like `!^/(search|data)/`

```
# Unless the request matches /search/ or /data/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(search|data)/
# Rewrite to the contents of the second group (.*)
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/(.*)$  /$2 [L,R=301]
```